# Why is $0^0$ also known as indeterminate?

Tags: exponentiation, convention, indeterminate-forms

I've seen on Maths Is Fun that $0^0$ is also know as indeterminate.  Seriously, when I wanted to see the value for $0^0$, it just told me it's indeterminate, but when I entered this into the exponent calculator, it was misspelled as "indeterminant".  Let's cut to the chase now.  I've seen this:$$5^0=1$$$$4^0=1$$$$3^0=1$$$$2^0=1$$$$1^0=1$$$$0^0=1$$and this:$$0^5=0$$$$0^4=0$$$$0^3=0$$$$0^2=0$$$$0^1=0$$$$0^0=0$$Right here, it seems like $0^0$ can be equal to either $0$ or $1$ as proven here.  This must be why $0^0$ is indeterminate.  Do you agree with me?  I can't wait to hear your "great answers" (these answers have to go with all of your questions (great answers).  What I mean is that you have to have great answers for all of your questions)!

Comment: You will need to explain the bar notation a bit more. Is $1||4^0 = 1·4^0$?

Comment: The reason is quiet simple: $0^0=0^{1-1}=0^1\cdot0^{-1}=\tfrac{0^1}{0^1}=\tfrac00$ which is undefined.

Comment: @k.stm the question says "(the bars are used to separate each of them)", why he doesn't just use commas is beyond me.

Comment: Who cares if it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Hakim That reasoning is flawed from the beginning: $0^{-1}$ is not defined, so you can't use it for concluding something else.

Comment: Hakim, the reason is "quiet" simple?  Weird...

Comment: @VladTheSmart You may be interested in my posting, "Oh, the ambiguity!" at my math blog https://dcproof.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, any number raised to the power of zero *does* equal $1$ because the base, or the number being raised to any power, gets divided by itself.  For example, $3^0$ equals 3/3, which equals $1$, but $0^0$ "equals" 0/0, which equals any number, which is why it's indeterminate.  Also, 0/0 is undefined because of what I just said.

Comment: Why should $0^0=0/0$? I can't see it: are you perhaps assuming that $0^{-1}$ is defined? As it is well known, if $0^{-1}$ exists in a ring, then $0=1$ and so $0=r$ for any element. Which means that $0^0=1$ is perfectly acceptable in that ring (anything is equal to $0$) as it is elsewhere. I've yet to find a *good* reason for not saying that $0^0=1$.

Comment: You _have_ noticed I put "equals" in quotation marks.  I've also seen that any power below zero raising zero to that power is actually dividing by zero.

Comment: I can't understand the quotation marks either, see the extension to my comment.

Comment: I don't know.  It might or might not equal that.

Answer (score 10):

The underlying problem here is that there are several *related but differently defined* concepts that are all notated $a^b$:

1. Exponentiation $\mathbb R\times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb R$ defined as repeated multiplication, which actually works as $R\times\mathbb N_0\to R$ for any ring-with-identity $R$. According to this concept $0^0$ is unambiguously $1$.
2. Exponentiation $\mathbb R^\times \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R^\times$ defined by extending the above to negative powers as reciprocals. This works for any field (or for the units of any ring). This doesn't define $0^0$ because it only works for numbers that have multiplicative inverses.
3. Exponentiation $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\times \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}\to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ defined by roots of integral powers (themselves defined as above). If one bothers to include $a=0$ in this definition we again get $0^0=1$.
4. Exponentiation $\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb Q\to \mathbb R_+$, as above plus reciprocals and $a^0=1$.
5. Exponentiation $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\times \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and/or $\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ by limits of the two above choices. This cannot be extended to give a value for $0^0$, because it has no limit for $(a,b)\to(0,0)$.
6. Exponentiation $\{e\}\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_+$ defined as a special case by *the exponential function*, which is again defined for example by power series. This extends to $\{e\}\times \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^\times$ for complex numbers.
7. Exponentiation $\mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$ defined by $a^b = e^{b\log a}$. This doesn't extend to $a=0$ at all, and only with difficulty to complex $a$; we get multiple values due to the non-injectivity of the complex exponential.

Fortunately these definitions agree for those $(a,b)$ pairs **where more than one of the concepts is defined**. That's why it doesn't usually create problems to use the same notations for all of them. Note that all the definitions that do give meaning to $0^0$ result in $0^0=1$. One way to express this would be that in practice $a^b$ denotes the *union* of all these functions.

In practice some disagreement can arise, however, when someone claims that $a^b$ is "not defined" for some particular $(a,b)$ just because one of the definitions doesn't work for that $a$ and $b$. This is especially the case for $a=b=0$.

When $0^0$ is said to be an **indeterminate form**, what that means is neither more nor less than the fact that the *limit*
$$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} $$
cannot be evaluated by taking limits of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ separately if $f(x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0$.

In particular, the word "indeterminate" *does not say anything about* what happens if we *do* apply one of the exponentiation functions to $(0,0)$ and we haven't got those zeroes by "taking limits under the limit sign".

Answer (score 2):

In the context of limits, $0^0$ is an indeterminate form because if the "limitand" (don't know what the correct name is) evaluates to $0^0$, then the limit might or might not exist, and you need to do further investigation.

Outside of limits, it's best to define $0^0$ as $1$ because the empty product - the product of no numbers - is defined as one.

Just like the sum of no numbers is defined as $0$:

$\quad \displaystyle \sum_{\phi(i)}x_i = 0$

where $\phi$ is a statement/property that is false for all $i$.

In product notation:

$\quad \displaystyle \prod_{\phi(i)} x_i = 1$

where $\phi(i)$ is a statement/property that is false for all $i$.

Defining $0^0 = 1$ simplifies many formulas. Many textbooks and online/offline soruces prefer not to define $0^0$ but that's pusillanimous in my view. $0^0 = 1$ works, we should use it.

Answer (score -3):

You're absolutely right. I would write it with limits, but the point is that there is no single value $0^0$ could be.

Comment: Sorry, but many people disagree with this “absolutely”.