# Number of solutions of $x(x^x-x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

How many solutions the equation $x(x^x-x)=0$ has in real numbers set?
$$1)\text{zero}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)\text{one}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)\text{two}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)\text{three}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)\text{infinity}$$

Here is my work:

To solve this problem I considered two cases: $x=0$ or $x^x-x=0$. for $x=0$ I think $0(0^0-0)$ is undefined in real numbers( because we have $0^0$). so we should solve $x^x=x$ however I'm not sure how we should solve this but it is easy to see $x=\pm1$ are the roots. so I think the equation has two roots in real numbers.

Is my answer right?

Comment: You can use that $0^0=1$

Comment: @Atmos Isn't  $0^0$ undefined?

Comment: No $0^0=1$ as $x^x=e^{x \ln \left(x\right)}$ that tends to $e^0=1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. However $\left(-1\right)^{\left(-1\right)}$ i don't know what it is

Comment: Ok. I think $a^{-1}=\frac1a$ so  $(-1)^{(-1)}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$

Comment: @Atmos Did you mean to use a negative rational, but noninteger in your example?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes ! Typing mistake, sorry

Comment: @Atmos: Your comment is completely wrong. Limits have **nothing** to do with the value of $0^0$; read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184974/21820).

Comment: @user21820 Thanks for the link provided. But considering $x^x$ we can continuously extent $x \mapsto x^x$ by giving the value $1$ when $x=0$ am I right ?

Comment: @Atmos: Indeed, you can do so ("continuously exten[d]") for the *very specific* function $(x↦x^x)$, but it is *not* relevant here because we are not talking about self exponentiation. $0^0$ should be defined as $1$ for reasons I had given in the linked post, but taking limits in any manner is *not* a valid reason.

Comment: @Atmos $0^0$ is not $1$. $\frac xx$ approches $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$, but that does not mean $\frac00 = 1$

Comment: @Atmos an equality and an equality of limits are different things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is either "two roots" or "three roots" depending on if you consider $0^0$ to be $1$ or undefined, and **both** are common, so it's a poorly written question.

Ignoring the $x=0$ case, you are right that $x^x-x=0$ is only possible when $x=\pm1$. We can divide through by $x$ to get $x^{x-1} = 1$. Some casework, now:

- One way to have $x^y = 1$ is if $y=0$; here, that means $x-1=0$, so $x=1$.
- If the power is nonzero, then only powers of $\pm 1$ can be $1$.